# Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined with Browserify

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browserify

I have a `Backbone` project that requires a fair amount of shimming for browserify.

I have set it up so that all of my underscore files are concat'd into one file `templates.js`

In turn I have to shim this into my project:

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
        .....
        "underscore": "^1.7.0"
        .....
 }

 ......

"browserify": {
     "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
},
"browser": {
"//": "SP Core Components",
    "jst": "./jst/templates",
},
"browserify-shim": {
     "jst" : {"depends": "underscore"}
}
 .....
```

**init.js**

```
 var JST = require('jst');
 var jsonobject = {};
 JST.staffOverview(jsonobject)
```

This will generate the following when trying to call :

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

So my question is, how can I set `underscore` as a dependency of `jst`

Comment: I think you need to specify how is underscore exported. You can try `browser: { "underscore": { exports: "_" } }`. I am not sure how is that variable `_` referenced in JST templates. Is it considered global or via require call ?

Comment: Ye, this was my thoughts. I don't want it as a global. I could just set `window._` with the require call. But I compile my `template.js` file with gulp. I have tried your suggest as well. Still no luck